# Why transpose a matrix here? (Neural network related)

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

while I take a look codes to understand Neural Network, I wondered about this code.

```
hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)
# The error of the hidden layer is calculated by recombining the errors of the output layer divided by the weight.
```

In this code, Why transpose a matrix?

I am afraid of violation of copyright, the entire code will post the GitHub address of original codes instead.

https://github.com/freebz/Make-Your-Own-Neural-Network/blob/master/neural_network.py

Comment: What is the structure of the matrix and what does it represent?

Comment: It(self.who) represent weights hidden layer to ouput layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transpose is necessary in order for the dot product (in this case equivalent to matrix multiplication) to be possible and calculate the right thing.

`self.who` is created in the line:

```
numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.onodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))
```

which makes it an OxH matrix, where O (rows) is the number of output nodes and H (columns) is the number of hidden nodes. `targets` is created in the line:

```
targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T
```

which makes it an Ox1 (2D) matrix. `output_errors` is then the same dimensions as `targets` and also an Ox1 column vector of O values (as would be expected):

```
output_errors = targets - final_outputs
```

In the implemented backpropagation algorithm, the hidden errors are calculated by premultiplying the output errors by the weights connecting the hidden layer to the output layer. From the [numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html?highlight=dot#numpy.dot) of `numpy.dot`:

> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.

So we need to transpose `self.who` to be an HxO matrix for this to work correctly in multiplying with an Ox1 matrix to give the required Hx1 matrix of hidden errors.